# Post request with API Key and Webview Flutter

Tags: flask, flutter, webview, aws-lambda, http-post

I have a flask application that once called from my flutter app, creates some HTML file and returns the location of the file name. Then my flutter app views that file using the 'webview_flutter' package.  This was working perfectly fine in the local development server. When I uploaded it to AWS LAMbda, I secured the application with some API key. So my question is how to call this API now with this key using http.post and then view the created HTML file with 'webview_flutter package' and that api_key.  Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First part for AWS LAMbda**

You can use package  https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart 
Authenticated access for API Gateway + Lambda please refer to
https://github.com/jonsaw/amazon-cognito-identity-dart/#for-api-gateway--lambda

code snippet

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:amazon_cognito_identity_dart/cognito.dart';
import 'package:amazon_cognito_identity_dart/sig_v4.dart';

void main() async {
  final credentials = new CognitoCredentials(
      'ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', userPool);
  await credentials.getAwsCredentials(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());

  const endpoint =
      'https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev';
  final awsSigV4Client = new AwsSigV4Client(
      credentials.accessKeyId, credentials.secretAccessKey, endpoint,
      sessionToken: credentials.sessionToken,
      region: 'ap-southeast-1');

  final signedRequest = new SigV4Request(awsSigV4Client,
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/projects',
      headers: new Map<String, String>.from(
          {'header-1': 'one', 'header-2': 'two'}),
      queryParams: new Map<String, String>.from({'tracking': 'x123'}),
      body: new Map<String, dynamic>.from({'color': 'blue'}));

  http.Response response;
  try {
    response = await http.post(
        signedRequest.url,
        headers: signedRequest.headers, body: signedRequest.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print(response.body);
}
```

**Second part for webview_flutter load response string** 
With webViewController, you can use controller.loadUrl 
You can copy paste run demo full code below 
code snippet

```
WebView(
                initialUrl: 'abc',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                  _loadHtmlFromString();
                },
              ),

_controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HelpScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HelpScreenState createState() {
    return HelpScreenState();
  }
}

class HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'abc',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                  _loadHtmlFromString();
                },
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.thumb_up,
                semanticLabel: 'Thumbs up',
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _loadHtmlFromString();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromString() async {
    String fileText = '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
    ''';

    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```